# Keras error : Input 0 of layer dense_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [16]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I want to compare two images represented by features vectors. For this, I used some existing code of siamese neural networks, with just the last part that computes the absolute difference of the two features vectors and then gives a similarity score (using sigmoid function).

So I tried to adapt the code, here is what I've got :

```
# Add a customized layer to compute the absolute difference between the encodings
L1_layer = tensorflow.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda tensors:K.abs(tensors[0] - tensors[1]), output_shape=(1,16))
L1_distance = L1_layer(K.constant(vectors(x_train, 0)))

# Add a dense layer with a sigmoid unit to generate the similarity score
prediction = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid', bias_initializer=initializers.Constant(0.1))(L1_distance)

# Connect the inputs with the outputs
siamese_net = Model(inputs= keras.layers.Input(shape=(2, 16)),outputs=prediction)
```

The function vectors(x_train, 0) computes a numpy array containing the two features vectors (each feature vector is also an array of length 16, so the final result of the function is [[vector1],[vector2]].)

When I execute the code, I encounter the following error, at the line where I create the Dense layer :

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1. Full shape received: [16]
```

I don't really understand, since I've explicitely specified that the output size of my Lambda layer is (1,16), which has 2 dimensions as expected by the Dense layer.

Thanks for your help.